# Javascript Save Multiple Checkboxes with LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, local-storage

I am trying to save checkboxes with localstorage so that when I refresh the browser, the checked boxes remain persistent until I have clicked a delete button.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
function save(){
var checkbox = document.getElementById('ch1');
localStorage.setItem('ch1', checkbox.checked);
}

function load(){    
var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ch1'));
document.getElementById("ch1").checked = checked;
}

function reload(){
location.reload();
localStorage.clear()
}

load();

<body onload="load()">
<input type="button" id="ReserveerButton1" value="save" onclick="save()"/>
<input type="button" id="Wisbutton1" value="delete" onclick="reload()"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="ch1"></input>

//additional checkboxes
<input type="checkbox" id="ch1"></input>
<input type="checkbox" id="ch1"></input>
<input type="checkbox" id="ch1"></input>

</body>
```

This is successfully saving one checkbox but I would like to save multiple checkboxes.  Therefore I am assuming that I need to I need add a loop in function save() ...

```
function save(){
var checkbox = document.getElementById('ch1');
  for (i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i ++) {
    localStorage.setItem('ch1', checkbox.checked);
  }
}
```

However I am a bit stuck on how to get those checked values with the load() call?

Cheers

Comment: you can't use multiple same id on the same page, use class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have multiple same ID's, they have to be unique.

Then, do like this

```
function save(){
  // Get all checkbox inputs
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  var arrData = [];
  // For each inputs...
  inputs.forEach(function(input){
    // ... save what you want (but 'ID' and 'checked' values are necessary)
    arrData.push({ id: input.id, checked: input.checked });
  });
  // Save in localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('inputs', JSON.stringify(arrData));

  console.log(JSON.stringify(arrData));
  // [
  //   {
  //     'id': 'ch1',
  //     'checked': false  // or true
  //   },
  //   ... and so on
  // ]
}

function load(){
  var inputs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('inputs'));
  // For each inputs...
  inputs.forEach(function(input){
    // Set the 'checked' value
    document.getElementById(input.id).checked = input.checked;
  });
}


<input type="checkbox" id="ch1"></input>
<input type="checkbox" id="ch2"></input>
<!-- And so on -->
```